# How can I remove all but the last 10 lines from a file?

Tags: bash, sed, tail

Is it possible to keep only the last 10 lines of a lines with a simple shell command?

```
tail -n 10 test.log
```

delivers the right result, but I don't know how to modify test.log itself. And

```
tail -n 10 test.log > test.log
```

doesn't work.

Comment: as a rule of thumb, never use a file simultaneously as input and output, you never know how it will end up.

Comment: Good advice. I just did `tail -n 10 test.log > test.log` and ended up with nothing (a blank file).

Answer (score 20):

You can do it using tempfile.

```
tail -n 10 test.log > test1.log

mv test1.log test.log
```

Comment: This works, thank you. 
However, **do NOT forget the `1`** because I did `tail -n 10 test.log > test.log` and am left with a blank file!

Answer (score 15):

```
echo "$(tail -n 10 test.log)" > test.log
```

Quotes are important. They preserve newline characters.

Answer (score 2):

Invoke ed command (text editor):

```
 echo -e '1,-10d\nwq' | ed <filename>
```

This will send command to delete lines ('1,-10d'), save file ('w') and exit ('q').

Also note that ed fails (return code is 1) when the input file has less than 11 lines.

**Edit:** You can also use vi editor (or ex command):

```
vi - +'1,-10d|wq' <filename>
```

But if the input file has 10 or less lines vi editor will stay opened and you must type ':q' to exit (or 'q' with ex command).

Comment: Odd not to see this answer being liked more. It’s elegant and also does the job on BSD rather than just Linux. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
ruby -e 'a=File.readlines("file");puts a[-10..-1].join' > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you may use a variable:

```
LOG=$(tail -n 10 test.log)
echo "$LOG" > test.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I wanted to demonstrate how process substitution can also help here:

```
cp <(tail -n 10 test.log) test.log
```

As process substitution results in a temporary file it doesn't overwrite `test.log` too soon. That's in contrast to the attempt in the question.