# linux cron truncate large file

Tags: linux, bash, csv, cron

I have a large csv file that I need to reduce to the last 1000 lines through a cron job every day.

Can anyone suggest how to accomplish this?

What I have so far are two commands but do not know how to combine them

For deleting lines from the beggining of the file the command is

`ed -s file.csv <<< $'1,123d\nwq'`

where 123 is the number of lines needed to delete from the beginning of the file

For reading the number of lines in the file the command is

```
wc -l file.csv
```

I would need to subtract 1000 from this and pass the result to the first command
Is there any way to combine the result of wc command in the ed command?

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove all but the last 10 lines from a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775383/how-can-i-remove-all-but-the-last-10-lines-from-a-file)

Comment: Use: `tail -n -1000 file > newfile; mv newfile file`

Comment: Shelter this works, but it would be more convenient if I could edit the file and not create a new file.

Comment: Slight improvement:
`tail -n 1000 file > newfile; cat newfile > file; rm newfile`
This preserves the ownership of 'file'.
If you run from cronjob, as root, mv will mean file ends up being owned by root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming bash is the shell, 'file' is the file (and it exists) :

```
sed -i "1,$(( $(wc -l < file) - 1000 ))d" file
```

Edit: the brief version above will not work cleanly for files with 1000 or fewer lines. A more robust script, handling all .csv files in a particular directory:

```
#!/bin/env bash

DIR=/path/to/csv/files
N=1000

for csv in $DIR/*.csv; do
  L=$(wc -l < $csv)
  [ $L -le $N ] && continue
  sed -i "1,$(($L - $N))d" $csv
done
```

Next edit: handle a directory with no .csv files?

Comment: Would it be possible to loop though all .csv files?